# Text Merging - How to do this in Python? (R source)

Tags: python, r, text

I have tried several methods but none worked to translate it to Python, specially because I have this error:

> 'str' object does not support item assignment

R can do the same with the following code:

```
f<-0
text<- c("foo", "btextr", "cool", "monsttex")
for (i in 1:length(text)){
    f[i]<-paste(text[i],text[i+1], sep = "_")
}
f
```

The output is:

```
"foo_btextr"    "btextr_cool"   "cool_monsttex" "monsttex_NA"
```

I would appreciate so much if you can help me to do the same for Python. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add some sample input, desired output, explanation of algorithm, and attempts at solving it? SO is not a coding service.

Comment: `'_'.join(iterable)`

Comment: i added the output from OPs script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R your output would have been (next time please put this in the question):

```
> f
[1] "foo_btextr"    "btextr_cool"   "cool_monsttex" "monsttex_NA"
```

In Python [strings are immutable](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-python-strings-immutable.htm). So you'll need to create new strings, e.g.:

```
new_strings = []
text = ['foo', 'btextr', 'cool', 'monsttex']
for i,t in enumerate(text):
  try: 
    new_strings.append(text[i] + '_' + text[i+1])
  except IndexError:
    new_strings.append(text[i] + '_NA')
```

Which results in:

```
>>> new_strings
['foo_btextr', 'btextr_cool', 'cool_monsttex', 'monsttex_NA']
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much Bernie. This problem has taken my head all day! Very useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>>
>>> f = ['foo', 'btextr', 'cool', 'monsttex']
>>>
>>> ['_'.join(i) for i in zip_longest(f, f[1:], fillvalue='NA')]
['foo_btextr', 'btextr_cool', 'cool_monsttex', 'monsttex_NA']
```